# How Can i build Data Driven framework with Watir Webdriver where test data will be excel files

Tags: test-data, watir-webdriver, cucumber

I need help to build data driven framework for [WATIR Webdriver](http://watirwebdriver.com/). Here my concern is, can we build data driven framework by reading data from excel in Watir-webdriver as we have option in Selenium+Testng framework

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Are you using Ruby? Then, I think this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475855/passing-values-through-excel-sheet-in-ruby-watir. If you using Java, then I suggest the Apache POI library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frameworks like Selenium and Watir itself do not provide functions to get data from sources like Excel. They are designed to automate and drive web-browsers with method that simplify this process.

As with most automation frameworks you combine them with a programming language and a test-runner. For most programming language Excel reading libraries are available, for Ruby this would be something like [spreadsheet](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet) read [the example guide](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/GUIDE.md).

So your data driven test framework would combine all four: Watir, testrunner, Excel library and programming language.

As you are also using [Cucumber](https://cukes.info/) I would also have a look at the follow SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955361/importing-csv-as-test-data-in-cucumber

Comment: Nice explanation @Niels van Reijmersdal